# Repeat SVG pattern horizontally on a larger container

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-pattern

I need to repeat an `svg` `<pattern>` on a horizontal `<rect>`.

I mean, the `svg` `<rect>` is larger that the pattern, so I need it to repeate horizontally on whatever space is left.

I want the main pattern to appear in the center, which is exactly what is happening now. I just need to make it repeat on both sides.

Right now, I can only get it to show once.

[image]

**Note:**

- The pattern is the black triangle
- The `1px dotted red` border is from the `svg` element

```css
.mySvg {
  width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<svg class="mySvg">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="wave" viewBox="0,0,150,50" width="100%" height="100%">
      <path d="M 0 50 l 75 -50 l 75 50" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#wave)"/>
</svg>
```

How can I make the pattern repeat on the space that is left?

Comment: you want to repeat only the triangle or the triangle and the space around?

Comment: Only the triangle.

Answer (score 4):

Use the SVG as background:

```css
.box {
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
  background:
    url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 -2 150 52"><path d="M 0 50 l 75 -50 l 75 50" stroke="black" /></svg>') 
    center/auto 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="height:100px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Temani, I tried using the svg as background and it works. I'm looking for a way to handle it using `svg` only. Do you think the background option is more "browser-compatible" than using svg patterns?

Comment: @cbdeveloper there isn't a difference in compatibility. Background can accept any kind of image and SVG are also images. So technically we are using *only* SVG but as background instead of element since the repeat is easier to handle

Answer (score 3):

In your code the pattern is having a width of 100%. It can't repeat. I gave the pattern a width of 25%. Also to make it fall in the middle I'm offsetting the pattern a 12.5% (25/2)
x="12.5%"

```css
.mySvg {
  width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<svg class="mySvg" viewBox="0 0 600 50">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="wave" x="12.5%" y="0" width="25%" height="100%">
      <path d="M 0 50 l 75 -50 l 75 50" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#wave)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks @enxaneta. From what I understood from your code, you were able to "center" the pattern, because you knew upfront the ratio between pattern and its container width. So you "adjusted" the `width` and `x` properties based on that. But I need this on a responsive container. So that `ratio` between pattern and container will be dynamic and not always `25%` like in this example. Is there a way that I can guarantee that the pattern will be centered under those dynamic conditions? Thanks

Comment: I'm starting to think that what I need is only doable with JS. I would need set up a listener for resizes and re-render the pattern on different positions to keep it centered when container resizes.